# Finding sum of Cn^2 coefficients of Fourier Series

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I have the following fuction with T=2 and x definde for [-1,1]

$f(x) =  \begin{cases} 
      2(x+1) & -1 \leq x\leq -0.5 \\
      1 & -0.5 \leq x\leq 0.5 \\ 
      2(1-x) & 0.5 \leq x\leq 1 \\
   \end{cases}
$

Now I have this question:

What's the value of $\sum_{n} |c_n|^2  $?

Options are 4/3, 2/3, 1/3 or 1.

Comment: [Parseval's identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_identity)

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it

Comment: @Someone If you don't mind, could you type up your solution to the problem and accept it? That is the general etiquette in this situation. That way your question is more useful to people who come across it via e.g. Google search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have T = 2.
We use Parseval (see the Wikipedia link someone commented).
In that formula we have to use T instead of 2$\pi$.

$ \int_{-1}^{-0.5} (2x+2)^2 dx  + \int_{-0.5}^{0.5} (1)^2 dx + \int_{0.5}^{1} (2-2x)^2 dx  
 = 4/3$

Now we just have to divide by T.

$4/3$ divided by 2 equals $2/3$.

So our answer is 2/3.